# My linux ubuntu server automatically creates these folders in its html directory . Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image]

```
W32ALPHA
W32MIPS
W32PPC
W32X86
WIN40
x64
```

Comment: A quick search for these folder names suggests that they are commonly used for printer sharing with cups, though they are usually created on a smb share and not in the wwwroot. Do you have anything print server related on the server?

Comment: not at all, its a separate server running Apache, PHP and MySQL only